# Drush generates .make file on server but it is not in the working directory?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, makefile, drush

I am a Drupal newbie and trying to clone my site which is hosted on an Aegir server (using BOA). I ran 'Drupal generate-makefile' command in the working directory (the directory in which site is located) and the file did get generated - but it is not in the working directory. I also tried forcing a path using 'Drupal make-generate path/to/store/makefile/makefilename' but the command ran and ended with an error 'call to an undefined function drush_make_error()'. Any ideas where the file may be getting generated? Also, any tips on how I can force a path for .make file would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on your Drush version, but with Drush 5.x the makefile is sent to stout.
This is how I use make-generate if I want my makefile written in `/root/`:

```
drush make-generate -r /path/of/my/drupal/installation > /root/drupal-org.make
```